# How to calculate conditional expectation $E[X|X \geq 0]$?

Tags: conditional-expectation

I only find some materials relating to conditional expectation like $E[X|Y=y]$.
How to calculate conditional expectation $E[X|X \geq 0]$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y = I(X \ge 0)$. Then, the density of $Y$ is given by:

$$\frac{f(y)}{\int_0^{\infty}f(y) dy}$$

You can then compute $E(X|X\ge 0)$ by computing $E(Y)$.

Comment: Thank you for such a prompt reply.
You mean the density of $X$?
Since $Y = I(X \geq 0)$, we have $E[Y] = E[I(X \geq 0) = P(X \geq 0)]$, right?\\
How to calculate $E(X|X \geq 0)$ by computing $E(Y)$? Could you please expain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

In general: if $A$ is an event with positive probability, then
$$E[X | A] = \frac{E[X \cdot 1_{A}]}{P(A)}$$
where the symbol $X \cdot 1_A$ denotes the random variable that is $X$ on the event $A$ and is $0$ otherwise.

One fact that may be helpful: if $A$ and $B$ are a partition of $\Omega$ (that is, $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A \cup B = \Omega$) then:
\begin{align*}
E[X] &= E[X \cdot 1_A + X \cdot 1_B] \\
&= E[X \cdot 1_A] + E[X \cdot 1_B] \\
&= E[X | A] P(A) + E[X | B] P(B).
\end{align*}

Comment: Here, $A$ is the event $X \geq 0$. Then follow the formula given,
$$
E[X|X \geq 0] = \frac{E[X \geq 0]}{P(X \geq 0)} .
$$
Is this right ?

Comment: I don't think the symbol $E[X \geq 0]$ has any meaning. Instead, you want $E[X \cdot 1_{X \geq 0}]$, which means "the random variable that is $X$ if $X$ is nonnegative and is $0$ otherwise".